# How to make an object stop at particular position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an simple AR app.What I want to do is, just wanted my plane object to move left from the image target and stop.But what happening is,the plane object is continuously moving to the left position. 
This is the code I have tried.

```
public GameObject plane;
private Vector3 direction;
public static Vector3 left;
private float moveSpeed = 3f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start(){
    transform.position += Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

can you please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Unity3d question? If so, you should tag it as such. Also, can you show your `Update` or `FixedUpdate` method if there is one?

Comment: Agreed, this looks like a Unity question. Also under what conditions is the plane meant to stop? I could give you very different answers depending on that.

Comment: Also, what is this script attached to? There are too many unknowns at the moment for anyone to give you a sensible answer.

Comment: Yes,its unity question.I can give u an example of ARToolkit i.e, without using the toolkit by using vectors I want my plane object to move left from the imagetarget and stop.Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Ok sure you want it to stop but under what conditions? Because it collides with something? Because some sort of friction slows it down? Because it has moved past a certain point? Please modify your question so that we can help you at the moment this is very vague.

Comment: Currently the object will not even be "moving" at all just jump to a certain position on start. You should take a step back and go through some basic [Unity Beginner Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/beginner-tutorials). In section 3 e.g. you'll find examples of movement by scripts.

Comment: @verlinsolutionstesting " I want my plane object to move left from the imagetarget and stop". Stop where? Why would it stop? What causes it to stop? What reason does it have for stopping?

Comment: @AdaRaider " Because it has moved past a certain point?" This is the reason .

Comment: @T_Bacon:       void Update()
                          {
                          transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime  * 
                              moveSpeed);
                           }

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link....it is not compiled in vscode
http://unityweltech.blogspot.com/2018/09/rigidbody-stops-at-position.html?m=1